# How to focus Material UI Textfield upon opening a modal?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If I autofocus the textfield, it loses focus once I click into the modal.

I place the modal here

```
 <NewOrgModal open={open} handleClose={handleClose} />
      <Drawer
        variant='permanent'
        sx={{
          display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' },
          '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            width: 110,
            // backgroundColor: '#0f041c',
            backgroundColor: '#180D24',
          },
          overflow: 'scroll',
        }}
        open
      >
```

And the TextField is in the Modal

```
    <Modal
      sx={{ position: 'absolute', top: '33%', left: '33%' }}
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <Card
        sx={{
          width: 600,
          height: 300,
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Typography marginBottom={3} variant='h4' fontWeight='600'>
          Create Org
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          onKeyDown={(e) => (e.key === 'Enter' ? createOrg() : null)}
          id='orgName'
          onChange={(e) => setOrgName(e.target.value)}
          value={orgName}
          sx={{
            width: 300,
            input: { textAlign: 'center', padding: 1, fontSize: 20 },
          }}
          placeholder='My Awesome Org '
        />
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          onClick={createOrg}
          sx={{
            marginTop: 2,
            borderRadius: 0,
            boxShadow: 'none',
            width: 300,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 600,
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Card>
    </Modal>
```

Is there a way to keep the textfield focused after clicking the button that opens the modal? If so, would there be any repercussions on having the textfield continue to focus after a specific action? e.g if I were to have other textfields in the future, would I need to think about other ways to not force the focus on the textfield in the modal?

Answer (score 4):

You can autofocus on text field like this:

```
<TextField autoFocus></TextField>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The Textfield autofocuses when the component is rendered however the Textfield is in the modal, and once I click the modal to open it, it loses its focus

Comment: It should work, if the textfield in the modal content block. I tested this on mui@5.12.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use ref and on the modal open action, you can do ref.current.focus() like this. try this way once

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
<Dialog open={open} onClose={closeHandler}>
   <TextField autoFocus></TextField>
</Dialog>
```

In dev mode, when using StrictMode, autofocus will not work, in production everything is ok